ffmpeg drawtext on ubuntu : ffmpeg does not change text location
I'm trying to edit a video with ffmpeg and I need the text to change randomly every 10 seconds, like in the site's own example. I tested this command:
ffmpeg -i "/home/editor/downloads/video_2023-07-10_17-53-05_7375753324605210932.mp4" -filter:v drawtext="fontsize=30:fontfile=/usr/share/hellotext=hellotext/share/World': x=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(w-text_w))\,x):y=if(eq(mod (t\,30 )\, 0)\,rand(0\,(h-text_h))\,y)" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy -preset slow -crf 18 -y output.mp4

When I execute this command, the video is edited and the text is added, but the timer that is supposed to move the text every 10 seconds does not work.
I tested it on Windows and it worked, but it didn't work on Linux.
